# How to use add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail" outside wp loop?

Tags: loop, plugin-contact-form-7, outside-wordpress

I am trying to trigger an add_action hook (add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "add_data_to_custom_table");) from outside the wordpress loop. The add_action hook is defined in theme's functions-custom.php.

in domain.com/test.php i have

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
define('WP_CUSTOM_TABLE', 'test_table');

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( '../wp/wp-blog-header.php' );

   include('../wp/wp-content/themes/customtheme/incs/functions-custom.php');

<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="417" title="Test Contact Form"]'); ?>
```

In this setup the add_action hook is not working.
If however i move the add_action hook definition to the theme's functions.php it does work.

My question: how can i include a functions-custom.php file outside the wordpress loop with working add_actions without including it from the theme's functions.php???

Comment: The fact that you are `require`ing a Core file means you are doing this wrong (about 99.9% certainty). Please explain the problem and perhaps someone can offer a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply put your `add_action` hook in a simple plugin. Activate the plugin and watch it run with the rest of the plugins.

If you insist on putting the `add_action` in the theme's `functions.php` then simply define a constant in your point of entry script, like this: `define('SCRIPTONOMY', true);`

Finally run a conditional in the `functions.php` testing for the constant.

Comment: your define('SCRIPTONOMY', true); seems to be a solution for my testing files.